# Touchpad suddenly stopped working

Tags: touchpad

The touchpad suddenly stopped working in my HP Pavilion laptop. External mouse works.
I'm running Ubuntu 10.10.
What are my options?

Comment: It started working when I tried this: http://superuser.com/questions/136568/touchpad-scrolling-is-gone-in-kubuntu-10-04-how-to-get-it-back  But now the Touchpad tab in the Mouse preferences dialog is gone :S

Comment: Does it stop working completely, or only moving the pointer doesn't work, but, say, scrolling does at the same time? I have such a problem with the touchpad in Ubuntu on my Toshiba AC100 -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ac100/+bug/1035208 , https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/830099

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you use " touchpad-indicator" - an indicator applet for easily managing your touchpad. Installation instructions are given in this link.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/touchpad-indicator-now-automatically.html

Comment: I installed this and removed the edit I mentioned previously. After a restart, it works fine now. Dunno what happened. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there another source to download the app from?

the code "sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator" no longer works.

Comment: And ... it works on the 12.04 beta 2, also, which means it will probably work as well when 12.04 LTS is released.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, switching to the linux console (say, Ctrl-Alt-F1) and back to X (Ctrl-Alt-F7) will make the touchpad work again. (This is a workaround around the bug, wothout a good fix and explanation.) -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ac100/+bug/1035208/comments/15

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your mouse or touch pad using `xinput`. First you should know the id of your device, for doing so type in a terminal:

```
xinput list
```

A list with input devices will appear, notice the id of your target device, then type

```
xinput --disable [id]
xinput --enable [id]
```

replacing `[id]` with the device ID you want to restart. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to pulse the FN+F7 (or the F-number with the symbol of the touchpad), always with the mouse not plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the configuration system, mouse and touchpad section, that let you to disable the option of "disable touchpad when writing" or something (I'm translating literally from french), please paid attention this opoption is not checked. I solved this issue in 12.04, 12.10, 14.04 and 15.10 Ubuntu OS, and I think it's an unknown bug or something. If you have disabled that option you will never have any more problem with your touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `i2c_hid` to the blacklist.

- first we need to open the file:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  ```
- and then we write the next line:   `i2c_hid`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in ubuntu 16.04:

1. Use external mouse and goto system settings
2. Goto Mouse & Touchpad
3. I found the Touchpad to be off so I switched it on. Touchpad started working fine afterwards